# problem getting my data from access 2003 db into c# (dbReader.GetString error)

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

**[got a bit further so its updated]**

Hello There, i really hope you are able to help me!

Now the first part of my code does work, and I do get my report numbers out in my combobox, and i'm able to write that number to a lbl. now I need to take that number and get the rest of my data from my Access 2003 database, and drop them in a string (my output). ( I dont really want all the data loaded into my mem when i open the program, so i belive only getting the [Rapport nr] until i choose one, where I will load the data into the string and save it there for now) :)

my problem is that this wont work!

```
output = dbReader.GetString(dbReader.GetOrdinal("Dato")).ToString();
```

**OBS: my error is now that it says i dont have any data in my rows or coloums**

my code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string aktuelRapportNR = "";
        string output = "";

        private string connectionName = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            + "Data Source=semcqdjh-access 2007.mdb;"
            + "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;";




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            #region Indlæsning af combobox, med rapport numre
            OleDbConnection Myconnection = null;
            OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;

            Myconnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionName);
            Myconnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = Myconnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Rapport nr] FROM AVR";
            dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int rapportNR;
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                rapportNR = (int)dbReader.GetInt32(dbReader.GetOrdinal("Rapport nr"));

                comboBox1.Items.Add(rapportNR);

            }

            dbReader.Close();
            Myconnection.Close();


#endregion
        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aktuelRapportNR = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lblAktuelRapportNR.Text = aktuelRapportNR;

            OleDbConnection Myconnection = null;
            OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;

            Myconnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionName);
            Myconnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = Myconnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Dato] FROM AVR WHERE [Rapport nr] =" + aktuelRapportNR;
            dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                output = dbReader.GetString(dbReader.GetOrdinal("Dato")).ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                output = "fejl eller tom";
            } 
            dbReader.Close();
            Myconnection.Close();

            label1.Text = output;
        }

        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: just saw it myself so i updated my post and got a bit further :P thanks anyway though :P

Comment: OBS: my error is now that it says i dont have any data in my rows or coloums

Comment: its okay :P its done now :D thanks for the help :P Well i dont think my problem is with the database, though i get my numbers out in the first part of the code, but not the other data in the second?

Comment: The statement returns as it should, i just tested it in access.. ill see if i can get more info from the debugger in vs :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured this out :D after a break i went back to this and tried to see if there where enother method i could use and there was :P i figured by the error that it was properly something about the types so insted of taking one out and trying to work around that i took the hole row out and placed it in a object array :P by using GetValues in the dbReader i got it to work, so i can now move on :D for those who might be interested! here is my code :P its not pretty but it works :P i allso took in som try catch just to make sure i check for errors and getting a friendly respons on that :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string aktuelRapportNR = "";
        string output;

        private string connectionName = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            + "Data Source=semcqdjh-access 2007.mdb;"
            + "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;";




        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            #region Indlæsning af combobox, med rapport numre
            try
            {

                OleDbConnection Myconnection = null;
                OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;

                Myconnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionName);
                Myconnection.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = Myconnection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Rapport nr] FROM AVR";
                dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                int rapportNR;
                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    rapportNR = (int)dbReader.GetInt32(dbReader.GetOrdinal("Rapport nr"));

                    comboBox1.Items.Add(rapportNR);

                }

                dbReader.Close();
                Myconnection.Close();
                txtStatus.Text = "Indlæsning Fuldført! Vælg venligst en rapport";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                txtStatus.Text = "Indlæsning Fejlet!";
            }

#endregion
        }


        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aktuelRapportNR = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lblAktuelRapportNR.Text = aktuelRapportNR;

            txtStatus.Text = "Du har valgt rapport nr.: " + aktuelRapportNR + "! Klik på export";
        }

        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                OleDbConnection Myconnection = null;
                OleDbDataReader dbReader = null;

                Myconnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionName);
                Myconnection.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = Myconnection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM AVR WHERE [Rapport nr] =" + aktuelRapportNR;
                dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                object[] liste = new object[dbReader.FieldCount];
                if (dbReader.Read() == true)
                {

                    int NumberOfColums = dbReader.GetValues(liste);

                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColums; i++)
                    {
                        output += "|" + liste[i].ToString();
                    }

                }

                dbReader.Close();
                Myconnection.Close();
                txtStatus.Text = "Export Lykkes! Luk programmet!";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                txtStatus.Text = "Export Fejlet!";
            }


        }


    }
}
```